# Design questions about Android chat application

Tags: android, multithreading, node.js

I am developing an `Android` app with a chat feature. `Nodejs` is being used at server end while [this](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) android SocketIO client is being used at user end. Following are my questions. Some are not questions but seek confirmation.

1. I must open socket (for the chat feature) in a worker thread, since it has to listen continuously.
2. For above purpose I cannot use `AsyncTask` since it should not be used for heavy lifting.
3. How to implement two way communication between the main thread and worker thread ?

Comment: If you want to make a bit of a serious chatting app, you'll have to look into XMPP (libraries: (a)smack(x)). It's the protocol most messengers use to some extend.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn why i need to follow xmpp protocol (or any) ?

Comment: You dont HAVE to do anything, but its an all worked-out protocol for chatting which also works based on sockets sending around xml messages which are already perfectly pre-defined. You can build a simple chat app yourself with your own sockets, but the more functionality you add (sending files, knowing if someone received your message, knowing if someone is online/active...), the closer you get to just copying XMPP yourself and you end up with being better off just using that from the beginning. You can also hook into things such as google talk and facebook messenger as long as you use XMPP.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn i want to upvote your comment but i dont have enough credit. anyway, that cleared some of my doubts.

Comment: coming back to my question, will those issues be automatically taken care if i use xmpp. i doubt , since they are about client design. can you throw some light on above issues ?

Comment: It's a complicated thing to get right. Basically, you will need the asmack library (java smack library, adjusted for Android) which provides you with all the XMPP protocol stuff. Secondly you need a server which supports XMPP, like this http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/

Comment: And yes, all stuff that any of your favorite chats do, are worked into the XMPP protocol to some extent. Per example, WhatsApp uses XMPP too. They did adjust it a bit though, to get some more advanced stuff working for them.

Comment: which one is preferable ejabberd or openfire ?

Comment: No idea, i'm not a server guy. OpenFire is the one i've heard of the most. I'd just go with whatever you can find the best tutorial and/or find the most answers for around here on stackoverflow.

Comment: For your questions, 1- Try to use popular web socket libraries that they manage to handle transport layer events for you via callbacks  2 - Yes, AsyncTask is not designed for this purpose 3 ) If callback runs in background thread, use Handler to pass messages to UI thread